# Loading shared library in Python that contains python API code?

Tags: python, ctypes

I'm playing around with automatically generating some C code, compiling it to a shared library and loading it with ctypes, and I'm curious if anyone can enlighten me as to what might be required to use parts of the Python API from within such a library (without creating a full-fledged module)

For example, I have some quick code hacked together:

```
PyObject* test() {
  PyObject* to_ret = NULL;
  PyGILState_STATE gstate = PyGILState_Ensure();

  to_ret = Py_BuildValue("i", 1+2);

  PyGILState_Release(gstate);

  return to_ret;
}
```

Which I compile to a .so and load with ctypes.

However, when I run the above I get:

```
>>> ctypes.CDLL("test.so").test()
138145104
```

So I'm clearly doing something wrong.  Any thoughts/tips would be welcome.

**SOLUTION**:
Aha, the above *does* work but ctypes by default expects an int return type and so is casting the PyObject* to an integer.  It seems there's no way to return an arbitary python object using ctypes, so generating a full module would seem to be the way to go.

Comment: Okay, amuse me. If you're using the Python API, why don't you want to write a module?

Comment: I'm just toying around with a library that lets you write quick snippets of numeric code in C and bind them to a function name.  Seems wasteful to build a module for each one and slowly pollute sys.modules.  Plus it's more of a challenge this way. =D

Answer (score 3):

It seems it can be done in Python 2.7, which supports a `ctypes.py_object` as a type.  I built a library from your example code and used the following:

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> t = CDLL('test').test
>>> t.restype = py_object
>>> t()
3
```